# Task for a delayed call of a function with the class and method names stored in a variable

Tags: c#, delegates, task, .net-4.7.2

I have a task that should delayed call a class method. But the call never comes through:

```cs
int timer = 1;
var component = "MyComponent";
var method = "MyMethod";
var objectId = "testId"; // app specific: for referencing to get the current instance. see example below.
var obj = FindEntity(objectId); // app specific: Reference of the current object instance
var type = Type.GetTypeFromHandle(Type.GetTypeHandle(obj.GetComponent(component)));
var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(method);
var actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(type);

Task.Delay((int)(timer * 1000)).ContinueWith(t => methodInfo.CreateDelegate(actionType));
```

The line in error is the last one here and I don't understand why this call doesn't work. No error is thrown either.

Here is a version for testing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FqmAQT

Thanks!

Comment: You need to invoke the delegate

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Is it to invoke the `methodInfo.CreateDelegate` method? What is the observable effect of invoking this method?

Comment: Yes, exactly. How do I do it?
The result should be that the dotnedfiddle example prints "MyMethod called" with delayed time. That means it should be `MyObject.GetComponent(...).MyMethod()` are called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. I think I got it now: ;)

```
Task.Delay((int)(timer * 1000)).ContinueWith(
    t => methodInfo.CreateDelegate(actionType).Method.Invoke(
        obj.GetComponent(component), null
    ) 
);
```